# Can't save in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to save an article in localStorage of Google Chrome on Android. I'm using the following code but the page where the content is supposed to display is showing blank screen. The articles are not getting saved.

```
function savePost() {
    var articleTitle = document.getElementById('entry-title').innerHTML;
    var articleDate = document.getElementById('entry-date').innerHTML;
    var articleContent = document.getElementById('entry').innerHTML;
    var articleLink = document.getElementById('browser').getAttribute('href');
    var saveData = {
        "title": articleTitle,
        "date": articleDate,
        "content": articleContent,
        "link": articleLink
    };
    if (localStorage) {
        var lastKey = Number(localStorage.key(localStorage.length - 1));
        for (var k = 0; k < 25; k++) {
            if (k == (lastKey + 1)) {
                try {
                    localStorage.setItem(k, JSON.stringify(saveData));
                } catch (e) {
                    if (e == ERR_QUOTA_EXCEEDED) {
                        alert("Storage full. Delete Some Items.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("Not supported for your device");
    }
}

function getSavedArticles() {
    var savedData, data;
    if (localStorage && localStorage['1'] !== 'undefined') {
        for (var n = 1; n < localStorage.length; n++) {
            savedData = localStorage.getItem(n);
            data = JSON.parse(savedData);
            $('<li><a href="#single" data-transition="slide" id="' + n + '"><h1>' + data.title + '</h1><p>' + getDays(data.date) + '</p></a></li>').appendTo("#saved_list");
            $('#saved-articles-list').on('click', n, function () {
                showPost(data.title, data.date, data.content, data.url);
            });
        }
        $("#saved_list").listview("refresh");
    } else {
        $("#saved_list").after('<div class=".error">No saved articles.</div>');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save-post').click(function () {
        savePost();
    });
    getSavedArticles();
});
```

Here is a demo:
http://smushbits.com/smushbits/www

Comment: Please format your code. Does it work in Chrome on non-Android devices?

Comment: @EdCottrell It doesn't.  I checked it just now on my pc.

Comment: Have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: @EdCottrell It's showing nothing strange.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution to check if localStorage is supported:

```
var localStorageSupported = (function() {
    try {
        var x = "test";
        localStorage.setItem(x, x);
        localStorage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
})();
```

Try this fiddle. 
I reformated your terrifying code:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3okus3f/)

Comment: Thanks for reformatting the code. locaStorage is supported but still my code is not working.

Comment: Try just setting or just removing something in localStorage on Andoid.